# AlarmManager return data to application

Tags: android, kotlin, alarmmanager

I'm trying to get a feature in my app that opens an ftp connection every night, compares the content of the ftp server to the contents of the sharedPreferences JSON and if there is a difference, upload the missing data to the ftp server.

So far I think I need to use an AlarmManager for this, so that the code runs even when the app is closed at night.
This is a completely new thing to me and I'm looking up some documentation and StackOverflow questions about it, but I can't really figure out if this is what I need to use for what I'm trying to do.

I found the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48124195/how-to-schedule-a-task-every-night-at-12-am) which contains a nice example of AlarmManager. But can it also retrieve data from sharedPreferences? I was also wondering if I can run an async task (using coroutines).

EDIT: I read something about a workmanager. Would this be a better solution for what I'm trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workmanager is introduced from Android 8. It is better then AlarmManager because it can manage the doze mode and more when you phone is in sleep mode. You can configure the workmanager to do the work each x mins with conditions (if the device connected, if the phone has % of battery ..)
The great issus with AlarmManager is that you don't garatute that it will be launched at the specific time because the system will manage all alarm with priority...

For more details : [link](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can fetch data from shared preferences from your `BroadcastReceiver`. And you can also run asynchronous tasks from your `BroadcastReceiver`, such as coroutines or threads.